# React axios logout not work, but request in rest.client work

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, token, logout

Hello i have problem in react. I try build laravel and react app. If i try send token via axios, i have error 401 (unauthorized), but if i try logout using vscode extension rest.client it's work. Token must be correct. i don't know why i have this problem.

Logout.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

const Logout = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
    
if(localStorage.getItem("token") == null) navigate("/login");

const logout = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout", {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        localStorage.clear();
        navigate("/login");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}

return ( <div>
    <button onClick={logout}>LOGOUT</button>
</div> );
}

export default Logout;
```

if i login user then i save token into localstorage.

[image: all localstorage values]

So if i get this token into rest.client it works

[image: Result in rest.client]

If i try logout using axios in react i have 401 error

[image: error logout #1]

[image: error logout #2]

Please help me

Comment: P.S this line ```if(localStorage.getItem("token") == null) navigate("/login");``` also not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add `headers` in third argument of your `axios.post` method:

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout", 
  {}, // here is supposed to be `data`
  {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thank you.. do you know also why this line ```if(localStorage.getItem("token") == null) navigate("/login");``` not work, this is line no. 8

Comment: Cool! What is the use of this line since you are redirecting after your axios request?